# Finding the lexicographic smallest string out of 3

Tags: java, computer-science, lexicographic, lexicographic-ordering

I have to create a program that takes 3 strings and orders them in a lexicographic order. I found out that for that you have to use the `compareTo()` method, the problem is that when I try to do if statements I see that they are int and not strings, and I do not know how to even show which one is the smallest one since there are so many different options. Is there an easier way to do it with that method (no arrays or anything allowed)?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SetAQuestion2
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        String first, second, third;

        System.out.print("Type three words: ");
        first = scan.next();
        second = scan.next();
        third = scan.next();

        int oneA = (first. compareTo (second));
        int oneB = (first.compareTo (third));

        int secondA = (second. compareTo (first));
        int secondB = (second.compareTo(third));

        int thirdA = (third.compareTo(first));
        int thirdB = (first.compareTo (second));

        System.out.println("The smallest word lexicographically is ");
    }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way would just be to put them in a list, then sort the list and grab the first element.

Comment: Yea but I HAVE to use compareTo

Comment: Well, technically, `sort` *does* afaik use `compareTo` behind the scenes. And note, you can cut down on how many cases you need to check. If first is smaller than second, you don't need to do that check again at thirdB. And if second is smaller than first for example, and third is smaller than second, you don't need to check if third is smaller than first, since that's implied. Some branching ifs would be ugly, but might be the only solution if you aren't allowed to use any reasonable options.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use `compareTo()` and simple `if/else` statements then you can set another string variable and compare the words. For example:

```
String first, second, third, result;
System.out.println("Type three words: ");
first = scan.next();
second = scan.next();
third = scan.next();

if (first.compareTo(second) > 0)
    result = second;
else
    result = first;

if (result.compareTo(third) > 0)
    result = third;
System.out.println("The smallest word lexicographically is " + result);
```

You can also use ternary expression instead of the if statements:

```
result = first.compareTo(second) > 0 ? (second.compareTo(third) > 0 ? third : second) : (first.compareTo(third) > 0 ? third : first);
```

I would also recommend using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) when using scanner so it gets automatically closed, so:

```
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    // rest of the code here
}
```

**Edit:**

As Andy Turner mentioned in his comment, you do not have to close the scanner or use try-with-resources if its reading from `System.in`. You only do that if its reading from a file.

Comment: I have no idea about ternary expressions or the try with resource thing but I will look into it. But that code runs perfect! It makes sense now how to use the compareTo method

Comment: @Devin `compareTo()` method returns 0 if the strings are equal, a positive number if the first string is larger, and a negative number if the first string is smaller

Comment: what happens if I dont use try for the inputs and it doesn't close?

Comment: @MoeA no, you don't need to close a `Scanner` if it is reading from `System.in`, because that closes `System.in`. You shouldn't close streams that you didn't open. This doesn't cause a memory leak: it causes a *resource leak* if you don't close a stream reading from a file.

Comment: @AndyTurner But isn't that what `AutoCloseable` does when using try-with-resources?

Comment: @MoeA yes. And you shouldn't use it as a resource in a try-with-resources block, because you shouldn't close it.

Comment: @AndyTurner Alright, edited the answer. Thanks for the clarification :-)

Answer (score 0):

You say that you have to *order* the 3 strings lexicographically. I take this to mean that you have to output the 3 strings in order, from low to high, rather that just find the smallest.

Here's some Java code to illustrate the logic required to do this with the minimal number of comparisons:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[][] tests = {
            {"a", "b", "c"},
            {"a", "c", "b"},
            {"b", "a", "c"},
            {"b", "c", "a"},
            {"c", "a", "b"},
            {"c", "b", "a"},
            };

    for(String[] s : tests)
    {
        order(s[0], s[1], s[2]);
    }
}

static void order(String first, String second, String third)
{
    int firstSecond = first.compareTo(second);
    int firstThird = first.compareTo(third);
    int secondThird = second.compareTo(third);

    if(firstSecond < 0)
    {
        if(firstThird < 0)
        {
            if(secondThird < 0)
            {
                print(first, second, third);
            }
            else
            {
                print(first, third, second);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print(third, first, second);
        }
    }
    else if(secondThird < 0)
    {
        if(firstThird < 0)
        {
            print(second, first, third);
        }
        else
        {
            print(second, third, first);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print(third, second, first);
    }
}

private static void print(String... arr)
{
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Output:

```
[a, b, c]
[a, b, c]
[a, b, c]
[a, b, c]
[a, b, c]
[a, b, c]
```